# How to logging with timed rotate file handler in Tornado?

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583916/how-to-manage-nohup-out-file-in-tornado) (how to manage nohup.out file in Tornado) about how to handle nohup.out file automatically when running a Tornado web service.

And I decided to use the `logging` module of Tornado to write my log files. I read about the [documents](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/log.html) of Tornado. The logging module it provides doesn't have the `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, I still cannot manage the logging files as dates.

So I want to know how to use `TimedRotatingFileHandler` in the logging module of Tonado?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx Tornado and Flask - What's a good start/stop script and keep-alive method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557450/nginx-tornado-and-flask-whats-a-good-start-stop-script-and-keep-alive-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rotating log files with my Tornado install.

I add this logging config line at the Tornado app startup:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open('logging.yaml', 'r')))
```

and then include a logging.yaml that looks something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bootandy/5546891):